# How to point to MasterDetailPage in Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

We had an application running on MVVM without any framework. Try to replicate a very basic MasterDetailPage using Prism library.

Copied the MasterPage from previous project and make some adjustment.

When I run this, it came up a white blank page ?!?! Any ideas?

**MasterPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

```
<MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <ContentPage Title="Master" >
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="RoyalBlue">
                <BoxView  HeightRequest="120" />
                <Label Text="Welcome to Athlosify" TextColor="White" FontSize="Small" Margin="20, 50, 0, 0" />
            </Grid>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,0" Spacing="10">
                <ImageButton>
                    <ImageButton.Source>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"  Glyph="&#xf6a0;" Size="25" />
                    </ImageButton.Source>
                </ImageButton>
                <Label Text="Home" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#707070"></Label>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HomeCommand}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,0" Spacing="10">
                <ImageButton>
                    <ImageButton.Source>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"  Glyph="&#xf224;" Size="25" />
                    </ImageButton.Source>
                </ImageButton>
                <Label Text="Activities" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#707070"></Label>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ActivitiesCommand}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,0" Spacing="10">
                <ImageButton>
                    <ImageButton.Source>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"  Glyph="&#xf30b;" Size="25" />
                    </ImageButton.Source>
                </ImageButton>
                <Label Text="Change Password" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#707070"></Label>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ChangePasswordCommand}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,0" Spacing="10">
                <ImageButton>
                    <ImageButton.Source>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"  Glyph="&#xf343;" Size="25" />
                    </ImageButton.Source>
                </ImageButton>
                <Label Text="Logout" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#707070"></Label>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,20,0,0" Spacing="10">
                <ImageButton>
                    <ImageButton.Source>
                        <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource MaterialFontFamily}"  Glyph="&#xf343;" Size="25" />
                    </ImageButton.Source>
                </ImageButton>
                <Label Text="About" FontSize="Small" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#707070"></Label>
                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding AboutCommand}" />
                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <pages:HomePage></pages:HomePage>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

**MasterViewModel.cs:**

```
public class MasterPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private DelegateCommand _homeCommand;
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public DelegateCommand HomeCommand => _homeCommand ?? (_homeCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExecuteGoToHome));

    public MasterPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    async void ExecuteGoToHome()
    {
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/HomePage");
    }
}
```

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public App() : this(null) { }

    public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/HomePage");
    }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<HomePage, HomePageViewModel>();
        containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<MasterPage, MasterPageViewModel>();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Worked out what causing it due to the Exception Settings sets by default. Once sets to trap Common Language RunTime Exception sets to all, found the error and it something to do with XAML format in the Master detail page. Fix it and worked ok.